# Donde veo los datos de los formularios de contacto que completan en mi pagina?

Tags: php, formularios

Tenía un formulario de contacto que me llegaba a mi mail cuando la gente lo completaba. Ahora ya no lo tengo y, en vez, tengo un formulario cuyo action es:

```
      <?php
$nameErr = $emailErr = "";
$name = $email ="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    }


  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);       
  }
}
```

?>

```
<h2>Contacto</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Por lo que entiendo, esto envia los datos a la misma página desde donde salen. Mi pregunta es, si muchas personas llenan ese formulario de contacto de mi página, ¿dónde se guardan los datos? ¿dónde los veo yo?

Comment: Hola, pedro. Por tu pregunta, parece que no tienes acceso a editar la página del formulario, ya que por lo que se entiende, es un script que muestra tanto el formulario como realiza el proceso de recibir los datos del mismo. Sin conocer lo que hace dicho script, es difícil decirte a dónde van a parar los datos...

Comment: No te entiendo, podrías ser más específico?

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es: ¿eres tú quien administra los archivos de la página web donde se encuentra el formulario? Si ese es el caso, puedes entrar a ver, revisar y editar el código del archivo de formulario. Si puedes ingresar allí, podrás contarnos qué sale, y así poder ayudarte. (Para entrar a administrar generalmente usas una plataforma como Cpanel, o acceso vía FTP al servidor)

Comment: Ahi puse todo el codigo php completo

Comment: Gracias por poner el código. Lo que se alcanza a ver, es sólo que reciben los datos y los almacenan en variables de PHP. Qué pasa luego con esos valores, no se ve en el script que nos compartes. ¿Ese script continúa hacia abajo, o eso es todo lo que tiene dentro? (No es necesario que lo copies y pegues aquí íntegro, puedes modificar algunos valores si se compromete la seguridad de tu página al publicar el código acá, la idea es saber qué hace, no los valores, sólo las instrucciones).

Comment: Ahi termina el codigo, pasa que lo estoy armando yo y mi pregunta era precisamente esa, que hacer con los valores que almaceno en variables y me vienen en el form, no se donde ponerlos

Comment: Ahh ok. Pues ahí depende de tus propias intenciones. ¿Deseas albergar esos datos para futuros usos? Si es así, es bueno almacenarlos en algún medio como una base de datos. Si no quieres una BD, puedes almacenarlos en archivos en tu servidor. En fin, las posibilidades son infinitas, y dependen todas de tus objetivos específicos. Como sea, si antes recibías por email dichos datos, con este script podrías volver a hacerlo (revisa la clase `phpmailer`, y ver ejemplos de su uso).

Comment: Mi idea es no usar ni base de datos ni mail, seria almacenarlo en un archivo de mi servidor, pero eso es lo que no se como hacer, quizas no fui clara en la pregunta, perdon!

Comment: Jejeje, pues no, en tu pregunta dices "¿dónde se guardan los datos?", no que quieres "guardarlos en un archivo" ^_^ Pero tranquilo, para eso son estas preguntas. En ese caso, te recomiendo leas la documentación de PHP para el manejo de archivos: http://php.net/manual/es/ref.filesystem.php --> Con esas funciones puedes abrir, crear, editar archivos en el servidor.